# Extracting full xml submission to web service using WSDL

Tags: java, xml, wsdl

I am working on a project that maps XML to a Java type by creating a collection to associate each Java attribute with its corresponding XML element. My code is very similar to this example:

```
private static org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc typeDesc =
new org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc(Login.class, true);

static {
    typeDesc.setXmlType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://schemas.actuate.com/actuate11", "Login"));
    org.apache.axis.description.ElementDesc elemField = new org.apache.axis.description.ElementDesc( );
    elemField.setFieldName("user");
    elemField.setXmlName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://schemas.actuate.com/actuate11", "User"));
    elemField.setXmlType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", "string"));
    elemField.setNillable(false);
    typeDesc.addFieldDesc(elemField);
}
```

Which is working fine. What I was wondering is if there is a way to actually save the entire XML submission that is processed by this class to a variable that can be output separately.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to store the XML inside a variable to output it separately? I can't understand what are you asking for

Comment: That's the thing. I'm not really sure. I'm new to working with this type of class and am unsure of the best way to get the information I need.

Comment: The best that you can do is use an XML parser to map your XML to a java object and work with that. http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/java-xml-tutorials/ If this is what you want tell me and I will add a good answer with more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Use @XmlMimeType("application/octet-stream") DataHandler data to handle the incoming attachment.

2.Create a temp file to store the xml: File tmpFile = new File(fileName);

3. Call writeStreamToFile(dataHandler.getInputStream(), tmpFile) to read stream from dataHandler and to write to tmpFile

   ```
   writeStreamToFile(InputStream inputStream, File file) throws IOException {
       BufferedReader br = null;
       FileWriter writer = null;

           br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
           writer = new FileWriter(file);
           String line = null;
           while((line=br.readLine()) != null)
           {
               writer.append(line);
           }
       }
   ```

4.Close the streams appropriately.